# Laravel + Capistrano publishing to DigitalOcean with ServerPilot

Tags: laravel, composer-php, capistrano

The sad part about searching for a solution today turned out that none of the provided answers were fully explained.

I believe my problem has really simple solution. When I run

```
cap production deploy
```

I get this output:

```
00:08 deploy:build
  01 composer install --no-dev --quiet
  01 /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@x.x.x.x: composer exit status: 127
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: composer exit status: 127
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as user@x.x.x.x: composer exit status: 127
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory
```

I've cut the unnecessary parts. I can upload .log file if needed, but I believe this should do it.

I think there's some issue with the path to the composer when capistrano tries to run composer, but I'm no sure. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Your `$PATH` variable does not contain the `$PATH` to your PHP executable in the CLI, or `capistrano` doesn't have access to it.

Comment: Path to composer is '/usr/local/bin/composer', $PATH is '/opt/sp/bin:/opt/sp/php5.6/bin:/opt/sp/apache/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'. What would be the reason for capistrano to fail to find it? I used the same ssh user as provided in the capistrano config

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the default PHP version for the PHP CLI. That will create `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/bin/composer` which is what will be used when you run just the commands `php` or `composer` rather than `phpX.Y-sp` or `composerX.Y-sp` (where X.Y is the PHP version).

First, make sure ServerPilot's `sp-php-cli` package is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install sp-php-cli
```

Then run `dpkg-configure` on it to select which version of PHP should be used:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sp-php-cli
```

More info in the ServerPilot article [How to Change the Version of the 'php' Command](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-change-the-version-of-the-php-command.html).

Comment: This helped. But I got a new error: `The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as user@x.x.x.x: composer exit status: 1
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: Nothing written`. Not sure where to look for an exception thrown. THe capistrano.log doesn't seem to show the error.

Comment: From deploy/production.rb these both lines fail: `execute :composer, "install --no-dev --quiet"` and `execute :chmod, "u+x artisan" `. But when I run them manually with the same user, they work

Answer (score 0):

Found out my git repository had different file structure than I was expecting. Everything was inside a folder called 'laravel'. That's why the commands weren't able to run

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Check it here:

http://bsosna.com/2017/05/05/how-to-add-task-to-capistrano/#troubleshooting